# replicate preg replace with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-replace

Is it possible to replicate this with javascript?

```
preg_replace('/(.gif|.jpg|.png)/', '_thumb$1', $f['logo']);
```

EDIT - I am not getting this following error for this peice of code,

> unterminated string literal

`$('#feed').prepend('<div class="feed-item"><img src="'+html.logo.replace(/(.gif|.jpg|.png)/g, "_thumb$1")+'"/>
                <div class="content">'+html.content+'</div></div>').fadeIn('slow');`

Comment: By replication do mean that you want the same errors that the original code has?

Comment: @Mark: I was just going to say... what about them `.` ?

Comment: To be strictly correct you should use `\.jpe?g` in both. The short `jpg` variant is just a concession to the DOS era.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of problems with the code you are trying to replicate:

- It matches "extensions" even if they aren't at the end of the filename.
- The dot in a regular expression matches (nearly*) any character, not just a period.

Try this instead:

```
'abc.jpg'.replace(/\.(jpg|gif|png)$/, '_thumbs$&')
```

I'm assuming that the string you are trying to replace contains only a single filename.

---

*See the documentation for [PCRE_DOTALL](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: Would be even nicer if you dropped the outer capturing group and used `$&`. +1

Comment: @nikic: +1 Nice, thanks! I completely forgot you can do that in Javascript. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, except that in JavaScript, `replace` is a string's method, so it would be rearranged a little (also, the array/object notation is slightly different):

```
f.logo.replace(/\.(gif|jpg|png)/, '_thumb.$1');
```

[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: @nikic When would an image's filename include a period and the extension more than once?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Damned, you are obviously right. I always make the mistake of forgetting that modifier and now I see that mistake even if it isn't a mistake... +1 for pointing out.

Comment: It's not completely impossible that a filename contains two extensions. It would be retarded, yes. But it's technically allowed and HTTP content negotiation schemes could indeed use a redundant `img0011.pnga.en.png`. Thus I would also avoid the `$` anchor but append `\b` instead.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc - Happens all the time in windows "file.gif.txt.jpg". Technically your missing the $ anchor.

Comment: @mario By avoiding the `$`, do you mean `end of string` or the `$1` that I used?

Comment: Yes I meant end of string `$` like in Marks example. While it describes the common case (extension last), this must not be true. Apache usually serves `img.png.en` as PNG file too. But I guess we're giving this too much thought for OPs example.

Answer (score 0):

```
somestringvar.replace(/(.gif|.jpg|.png)/, replacementValue)
```